# Use short URL to refer to MediaWiki site with Apache virtual host

Tags: apache, mediawiki, short-url

My setup on Apache:

- /var/www/sandbox.example.org/wiki
- I have a permanent rewrite from http://sandbox.example.org to https://sandbox.example.org; there is an http config file and an https config file
- In Apache config files: DocumentRoot /var/www/sandbox.example.org/wiki
- In Apache config files: DirectoryIndex index.php

I put Mediawiki in the /var/www/sandbox.example.org/wiki folder and then did the installation.

LocalSettings.php got automatically: $wgScriptPath = "";

As URL in the browser, I get: https://sandbox.example.org/index.php?title=MainPage

What I want: https://sandbox.example.org/wiki/MainPage

I followed / tried instructions on https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Short_URL/Apache, but with no effect.

How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution! For the ones who are interested:

In the virtual host configuration file, there is among others within the <VirtualHost *:80> tag:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/sandbox.example.org
DirectoryIndex w/index.php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?wiki(/.*)?$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/w/index.php [L]
```

And in the LocalSettings.php of the MediaWiki installation:

```
$wgArticlePath = "/wiki/$1";
$wgUsePathInfo = true;
```

So now I have: http://sandbox.example.org/wiki/MainPage instead of http://sandbox.example.org/w/index.php?title=MainPage.

Comment: One additional thing: mod_rewrite.so needs to be enabled.